Mollie API - Cancel payment
I'm implementing a feature which required cancellation payment on Mollie, I saw that the IsCancellable is always false, so my question is, what kind of payment methods can we cancel on mollie, using the API v2 => Some payment methods can be cancelled by the merchant for a certain amount of time, usually until the next business day. Or as long as the payment status is open. Payments may be canceled manually from the Mollie Dashboard, or programmatically by using this endpoint.
I was trying the API v2 => DELETE https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments/*id*
=> The payment is not cancellable

Judging by this github issue, the payment is only cancelable when it is:

a payment via bank transfer that is still outstanding;
collection that has not yet been sent to the bank

So, in most cases, the payment would not be cancellable. You are not in charge if setting the isCancellable parameter, it is reflecting the bank transfer state. The example would probably be:

some credit card payments
transfers through the banks that only process transactions on
business days (yep they exist).

Looking at the docs for the payment types, looks like klarnapaylater, klarnasliceit, and possibly other types (for example paypal if the payment was held) would be cancellable for some time.
If your feature is to allow the customer to cancel their purchase (which you handled through mollie), the isCancellable parameter is probably not what you need - it indicates to you that the customers' payment could still be cancelled (as in, you can stop the money from being removed from their account). If you want to initiate the cancellation from your side for any payment method, that's usually handled as a refund, which is a separate API (docs)
Edit: judging by the FAQ I suspect the only cancelable-by-you (as in, the app owner) payments might be those in "authorized" status, which is

only available for Cards, Apple Pay, Klarna Slice it or Klarna Pay later.


I've seen the github issue before but it was 2018 and I thought there's new update.
It's confusing me, mollie does not list the payment methods that we can cancel.

I suspect that's because mollie is not in charge of what is cancellable or not, the payment provider is. E.g. Paypal could theoretically do all transactions in bulk at midnight 5 years ago (so the payment would be cancellable until midnight), and then updated and now they take the funds instantly (and now it's not cancellable at all), and mollie has no way of keeping up with that - thay are just transmitting the info to you.  Again, if your feature is essentially "customer changed their mind soon after transaction", you probably want the refund API instead of that "cancellable" thing.

Also, btw, there is some extra info in the FAQ: apparently there is a possibilty that SEPA Direct Payment is cancellable; you can also cancel a "captured" payment; etc (just search for "cancel" here: https://help.mollie.com/hc/en-us/categories/360002830740-Payment-methods-and-transactions)
